# Selecting a nth row from a table using SQL in Oracle, MYSQL and SQL Server assuming there is no ordered column in the table

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, top-n

Let us take a table t1

```
SQL > Select * from t1;
```

## COL1

```
    9
    1
    8
    6
    4
```

Q) Query to retrieve third row from the table.

A) Oracle :

```
SQL > select col1 from (select col1, row_number() over(order by rowid) rn from t1) where rn=3;
```

As rowid psuedo column doesn't exist in other databases, how can retrieve a nth record from a table in databases like MYSQL, SQL Server etc.

Comment: Select * from t1 LIMIT n,1; where n = 3 for third row

Comment: You can't find a syntax for this supported by all of MySQL, Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: Short answer, don't do this as a relational database table is logically an unordered set of rows, That being said, one could order by the physical location pseudo column in SQL Server using a CTE: `WITH a AS (
     SELECT col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY %%physloc%%) rn FROM t1
    )
    SELECT col1
    FROM a where rn=3;`

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server also, you have the `ROW_NUMBER` Function

You Can Go like

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EmployeeID),
        *
        FROM dbo.Employee
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
        WHERE RN = 5--To Get the 5th Record
```

Comment: There is no column in my table as employeeID. Let us take no row in the table is in a order.

Comment: This is Just an example. you Need to change the Column and Table names according to your required

Answer (score 0):

for mssql you can use row_number() window funciton

```
select * from 
(
select *, row_number() over(order by col1) rn from t
) t1 where t1.rn=1 -- 2 or 3, n
```

Comment: Ordering the column by col1 will give answer 6. But i want the third record in the table which is 8